# Neo4j in cloudfoundry.

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cloud-foundry

I am pushing neo4j 2.3.3 application to cloudfoundry. 
I have neo4j server and neo4j running cloud, which also runs in my local. 
As of the data set is inside the neo4j server. 
Neo4j browser is node js application, which start on command "grunt server"
but the browser starts up at http://localhost:9000.
How to make the nodejs application (neo4j browser) listen to 9000. I know there process_env. But how to implement it here. 
Neo4j browser has a js file(connect.js) which loads the http protocol , host and port. 
I need some guidance, in making modifications here. 
I have previously read VCAP_SERVICES into a java code. 
1. how to add port 9000 to cloud foundry. 
2. how to read port env variable from cloud foundry to jd file. 
or
Is there any other way around. ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a node js application. 
In local : the host name is 127.0.0.1 
port is 9000. 
server is running 
Neo4j browser is a node js application started using "grunt server" 
There are no error in the log. 
But I how launch the browser. I get 502 bad gateway error. 
Local host :127.0.0.1 then what is the host address for cloud foundry.
I did try 0.0.0.0

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html

```
-------------- 
var vcapport = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000; 
                  var vcaphost = process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || '0.0.0.0'; 
          server 
            .listen(vcapport, vcaphost) 
            .on('listening', function() { 
              var address = server.address(); 
              //var hostname = options.hostname || '0.0.0.0'; 
                          var hostname = vcaphost; 
              var targetHostname = 'browser.cfappstpanpz2.ebiz.verizon.com'; 

              var target = options.protocol + "://" + vcaphost +":" + vcapport; 
                          //var target = 'http://browser.cfapps.io/';

              grunt.log.writeln('Started connect web server on ' + target); 
              grunt.config.set('connect.' + taskTarget + '.options.hostname', hostname); 

              grunt.config.set('connect.' + taskTarget + '.options.port', address.port); 
                  grunt.log.writeln('server.address ' + address); 
                          grunt.log.writeln('address.port ' + address.port); 
                          grunt.log.writeln('hostname ' + hostname); 
                          grunt.log.writeln('vcapport ' + vcapport); 
                          grunt.log.writeln('vcaphost ' + vcaphos); 

              grunt.event.emit('connect.' + taskTarget + '.listening', hostname, address.port);
```